# RegEx for removing whitespace in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Trying to make a very simple HTML minifier that only removes white space between tags?

I think the best way is with a JavaScript Regular Expression? but can never work out how to do them correctly.

```
<p>leave white spaces</p> <p>leave white spaces</p>
```

After  minify:

```
 <p>leave white space</p><p>leave white space</p>
```

trying to target the space bewtween `>` here `<`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider using `DOMParser` instead, and then `remove`-ing all text nodes which, when trimmed, are empty:

```js
const input = `<p>leave white spaces</p> <p>leave white spaces</p>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, 'text/html');
[...doc.body.childNodes].forEach((node) => {
  if (node.nodeType === 3 && node.textContent.trim() === '') {
    node.remove();
  }
});
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

If here we wish to or have to use regular expressions, we can add a non-capturing group `(?:\s+)` in between the open and close tags and replace it with an empty string using an expression such as:

```
<\/[a-z]+>(?:\s+)<[a-z]+>
```

We can add additional boundaries to this expression, however if our inputs would be just similar to the one exampled in the question, this would suffice.

For instance, for `h1` tags, we would be expanding our char list:

```
<\/[a-z0-9]+>(?:\s+)<[a-z0-9]+>
```

For, uppercase instances, if any, we would be adding an `i` flag.

#### TEST

```js
const regex = /<\/[a-z]+>(?:\s+)<[a-z]+>/gm;
const str = `<p>leave white spaces</p>   <p>leave white spaces</p>    <p>leave white spaces</p>   <p>leave white spaces</p><p>leave white spaces</p>   <p>leave white spaces</p>    <p>leave white spaces</p>   <p>leave white spaces</p>
<p>leave white spaces</p>   <p>leave white spaces</p>    <p>leave white spaces</p>   <p>leave white spaces</p><p>leave white spaces</p>   <p>leave white spaces</p>    <p>leave white spaces</p>   <p>leave white spaces</p>
<p>leave white spaces</p>   <p>leave white spaces</p>    <p>leave white spaces</p>   <p>leave white spaces</p><p>leave white spaces</p>   <p>leave white spaces</p>    <p>leave white spaces</p>   <p>leave white spaces</p>

`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4Uy6ar/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]